# Ruby on Rails 4.2.0: How to find the directories set for loading libraries etc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, path, environment-variables, classpath

Is there a environment variable and some command-line options to check my rails application's directories that are set automatically or configured somewhere so that rails know where to load libraries etc.?

As a compare, ruby has a command line option (-I):

> `ruby -I path:another/path:/usr/lib rubyfile.rb arg1 arg2`

such that users can set the directories where libs can be looked up by Ruby.

Similarly, here I am asking if for rails there is a similar way to check the loading paths for Rails applications? Or if there is certain variable set somewhere?

***Highlight: I am using Rails version 4.2.0. The config/application.rb sample code doesn't appear to contain config.autoload_paths, not even in comments, which used to be the one for Rails 3 and Rails 4.1.x.***

And, how would the Rails application know where to look up for Gems, etc.?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this file:

```
config/application.rb
```

Specifically, you add this setting:

```
config.autoload_paths
```

You can add to the autoload paths like this:

```
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('mydir')
```

The `config.autoload_paths` accepts an array of paths from which Rails will autoload constants.

The default is all directories under `./app`, such as `controllers`, `models`, etc.

The default does *not* autoload from the typical top-level `./lib` directory. If you want to autoload from lib:

```
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
```

See the [Rails Guides for Configuring](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-general-configuration)

Rails knows where to look for gems a variety of ways: typically your environment `GEM_PATH` or the `bundler` gem `bundle exec` command. For example, I personally bundle my Rails gems into `./vendor/bundle/`.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer! However, this does not seem to be the one for Rails version 4.2.0. The application.rb does not contain config.autoload_paths variable. Actually, I didn't find it throughout the whole Rails application generated under version 4.2.0. I know it was there for Rails 3.x.x, though. I will update my question to highlight my Rails version.

Comment: Rails 4.2 uses the same setting -- it's just that the default new app doesn't put it in, so you need to add it yourself.

Comment: Oh, thanks! That makes sense. Just a quick follow-up: the Guide said the default is all dirs under app/, then the lib/ dir is NOT by default included? I am also confused and surprised that the default is just all dirs under app/ - then how would the Rails applications load those Gems without knowing where they are?